# .NET deserialization - using different assembly

Tags: .net, assemblies, serialization

I've got a problem I can't find any solution for. I have a textfile containing Serialized objects. I need to extract that data. I have the code of class that was used to serialize and the entities but not the original assembly.

I can't deserialize this because the serialization class wants the exact same assembly to deserialize as the one used to serialize. Is there some tool that will allow me to extact this data easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I will have to play around with BinaryFormatter.Binder .. right?

More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make a new assembly with the same name.

Comment: easiest way, but I don know the assembly name, that is why am asking about some tool like Reflector using which I can inspect the serialized file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your question, the Serialized objects are possibly using (having members of ) classes/interfaces/datatypes an assembly that you do not have.

So I guess the short answer is no, you can't